# Way to set no value datetimepicker if disabled

Tags: c#

Is there a way to set no value datetimepicker if disabled?

```
private void radActualSales_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radActualSales.Checked == true)
    {
        startTimePicker.Enabled = true;                
        endTimePicker.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        startTimePicker.Enabled = false;
        startTimePicker.Value.ToString("00:00:00");
        endTimePicker.Enabled = false;
        endTimePicker.Value.ToString("00:00:00");
    }
}
```

If the user checks the `radActualSales` radio button it allows the user to input time but if not I want to give it a default time like 12:00am for start time and 11:59pm for end time. How do I do this?

Comment: So you don't want empty date pickers, but instead you want to set the time to `12:00 am` and `11:59 pm` respectively, is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void radActualSales_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radActualSales.Checked == true)
            {
                startTimePicker.Enabled = true;
                endTimePicker.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
            startTimePicker.Enabled = false;
            startTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Today.AddHours(0);
            endTimePicker.Enabled = false;
            endTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Today.AddHours(-0.01);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5428/Nullable-DateTimePicker) solution:

> I have overridden the Value property to accept Null value as
>   DateTime.MinValue, while maintaining the validation of MinValue and
>   MaxValue of the standard control. That's all there's to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can asign a new value for the DateTimePicker.

```
private void radActualSales_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radActualSales.Checked == true)
        {
            startTimePicker.Enabled = true;                
            endTimePicker.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            startTimePicker.Enabled = false;
            //day, month, year, hour, minute, second
            startTimePicker.Value = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 11, 59, 59);
            endTimePicker.Enabled = false;
            endTimePicker.Value. = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```